# Whats wrong here in config array of Zend Captcha?

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha

I am using Zend_Form_Element_Captcha to create Captcha image as follows :-

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(
                   'captcha',
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Please write the characters you see in the image:',
                        'captcha' => array(
                                         'captcha' => 'Image',
                                         'wordLen' => 6,
                                         'timeout' => 900,
                                          'font' => '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',

                                     )
                        )
    );

$form = new Zend_Form();

$form->addElement($captcha);
```

This is creating Captcha Image but not in proper way. **Letters are not at all readable.**
This is what I am getting...

[image]

[image]

I also tried to change font, but ended up in same. Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you tried using other fonts?

Comment: Yes, as i have said, i ended up in same. I also tried with only 'font'=>'arial', but again, same result.

Comment: are you sure that it is accessing the font directory that you assign?

Comment: no, how can i check that? (but it is not showing any error also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code on local environment.If you are using windows then use following code.
I used absolute path to font.

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(
                        'captcha',
                        array(
                            'label' => 'Please write the characters you see in the image:',
                            'captcha' => array(
                                'captcha' => 'Image',
                                'wordLen' => 6,
                                'timeout' => 900,
                                'font' => 'C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf',
                                'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha/',
                                'imgUrl' => '/captcha/'
                            )
                        )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(
   'captcha',
    array(
        'label' => 'Please write the characters you see in the image:',
        'captcha' => array(
             'captcha' => 'Image',
             'wordLen' => 6,
             'timeout' => 900,
             'dotNoiseLevel' => 20,
             'lineNoiseLevel' => 3,
             'fontSize' => 25,
             'font' => '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',

         )
        )
);
```